# Replace link url in body of e-mail sending per application java

Tags: java

I have application send e-mail to customer and I use [`javax.mail.Transport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Transport.html) Class to do this. I want include an URL link in body of e-mail but I prefer mask the link with sentence for example "click here" instead of "https://link.com" .

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it supports html. Create a place holder `{email_link}`  in the email templates and replace it using regular expression like this:

```
body = body.replace("{email_link}","<a href='https://link.com'> click here </a>");
```

If you don't have any tag just replace the word with a link like this:

```
body = body.replace("LINK_WORD","<a href='https://link.com'> click here </a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem I make this instruction :

**message.setContent(msg, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");**

it works fine